# Unable to get the final calculated grade value for a student in a course

Tags: desire2learn

I have used the following api call

/d2l/api/le/1.2/courseid/grades/final/calculated/studentid

but I get an error message saying Error: Unknown: NOT_FOUND.

Does that mean the grade isn't posted or is it a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

That API gets used to initiate a final grade re-calculation for a student. Your 404 Not Found error most likely means one of these things:

- You are using the wrong HTTP Method for this route (i.e. you're making a PUT or GET call, when it should be a POST with an empty body)
- Your LMS doesn't support the API version you're using (1.2 in your example)
- You haven't specified the correct LMS Org Unit ID value for the course offering
- You haven't specified the correct LMS User ID value for the student

Note that "correct value" for those last two must mean that the two entities exist *and* have an appropriate relationship (i.e. they both validly identity a course, and a user, respectively, *and* that the user is explicitly enrolled in the course offering with a gradeable role).